# Gstreamer file stream to UDP

Tags: linux, gstreamer, gst-launch

Im trying to stream a mp4-file from one pc and open it on another by using Gstreamer

**Reciever**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=9002 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, ssrc=(uint)1" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink   sync=false
```

**Sender**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e filesrc location=/home/user/Downloads/sample.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 ssrc=1 ! udpsink host=192.168.88.249 port=9002
```

Now the problem is that nothing happens. I don't get any errors. When going true the debuginformation i can't find any critical errors.

GST_DEBUG=3 give only some warnings

```js
0: 00: 00.045395951 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux_types.c: 222: qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type iods
0: 00: 00.045462394 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux_types.c: 222: qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type gsst
0: 00: 00.045480551 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux_types.c: 222: qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type gstd
0: 00: 00.045496165 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux_types.c: 222: qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type gssd
0: 00: 00.045510328 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux_types.c: 222: qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type gspu
0: 00: 00.045524261 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux_types.c: 222: qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type gspm
0: 00: 00.045536699 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux_types.c: 222: qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type gshh
0: 00: 00.045585159 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux.c: 2639: qtdemux_parse_trex: < qtdemux0 > failed to find fragment defaults
for stream 1
0: 00: 00.045732466 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN qtdemux qtdemux.c: 2639: qtdemux_parse_trex: < qtdemux0 > failed to find fragment defaults
for stream 2
0: 00: 00.046036080 15247 0x95dcf0 WARN basesrc gstbasesrc.c: 2396: gst_base_src_update_length: < filesrc0 > processing at or past EOS
```

Caps

`/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = "video/x-h264\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)avc\,\ alignment\=\(string\)au\,\ level\=\(string\)5.1\,\ profile\=\(string\)high\,\ codec_data\=\(buffer\)01640033ffe1001867640033acb400800090d0800000030080000018078c195001000468ce0bcb\,\ width\=\(int\)4096\,\ height\=\(int\)2304\,\ framerate\=\(fraction\)24000/1001\,\ pixel-aspect-ratio\=\(fraction\)1/1\,\ parsed\=\(boolean\)true"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H264\,\ packetization-mode\=\(string\)1\,\ profile-level-id\=\(string\)640033\,\ sprop-parameter-sets\=\(string\)\"Z2QAM6y0AIAAkNCAAAADAIAAABgHjBlQ\\\,aM4Lyw\\\=\\\=\"\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)1\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)3976213474\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)24166\,\ a-framerate\=\(string\)23.976023976023978"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H264\,\ packetization-mode\=\(string\)1\,\ profile-level-id\=\(string\)640033\,\ sprop-parameter-sets\=\(string\)\"Z2QAM6y0AIAAkNCAAAADAIAAABgHjBlQ\\\,aM4Lyw\\\=\\\=\"\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)1\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)3976213474\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)24166\,\ a-framerate\=\(string\)23.976023976023978"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = "video/x-h264\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)avc\,\ alignment\=\(string\)au\,\ level\=\(string\)5.1\,\ profile\=\(string\)high\,\ codec_data\=\(buffer\)01640033ffe1001867640033acb400800090d0800000030080000018078c195001000468ce0bcb\,\ width\=\(int\)4096\,\ height\=\(int\)2304\,\ framerate\=\(fraction\)24000/1001\,\ pixel-aspect-ratio\=\(fraction\)1/1\,\ parsed\=\(boolean\)true"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = "video/x-h264\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)avc\,\ alignment\=\(string\)au\,\ level\=\(string\)5.1\,\ profile\=\(string\)high\,\ codec_data\=\(buffer\)01640033ffe1001867640033acb400800090d0800000030080000018078c195001000468ce0bcb\,\ width\=\(int\)4096\,\ height\=\(int\)2304\,\ framerate\=\(fraction\)24000/1001\,\ pixel-aspect-ratio\=\(fraction\)1/1"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: timestamp = 3976213474
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: seqnum = 24166`

Comment: what happens when you run gst-launch with `GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 ...`? I think you should copy some caps that are printed on sender to receiver..

Comment: what about streaming with mpegtsmux as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36564386/3876138) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34088035/3876138) question?

Comment: also check [this readme](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/gst/rtp/README#n251) what is needed to run rtp stream (copy paste caps porinted at server)

Comment: @otopolsky i tried it with mpegtsmux and to open it with vlc on the other pc. Which failed also. I can do a vlc rtp stream from one to the other so i think it can't be a network issue

Comment: what do you mean failed? lets test it with sample video input instead of file with ` videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=10.x.y.z port=5000` and on vlc on another PC in same LAN play stream with `rtp://@:5000`

Comment: can you stream the mp4 file with vlc to other vlc on another PC(not using gstreamer at all)

Comment: I tried this yesterday also and that works. Playing the file directy to a videosink on the same pc with `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/user/Downloads/sample.mp4 ! qtdemux ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink` also works. And i can stream the file with vlc from one computer to another.

Comment: ok can you update the question what you tried so far (also the pipe for mpegtsmux test)..